# Move from the (soon-to-be-skinny)controller to the (not-so-fat)model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, model, controller

I barely understand rails, let alone ruby, so this is probably an easy one. In one of my controller's show action I have a variable that I have defined to calculate the total of some items, looks something like this:

```
@total_of_items = SomeModel.where(:user_id => @user).sum(:amount)
```

This obviously collects all of the amount attributes of this particular user and adds them up. So in my view I just call:

```
<%= @total_of_items %>
```

And it shows up. So two questions. First, is this really the best way to do something like this? Because I may want to take this value and show it in another user's view to compare the two, or something like that. It seems like in order to do that this would have to be a method in the model? I'm just not sure.

My second question is how to take a variable defined in the controller and put it in the model. It seems like that's the more "skinny controller fat model" way of doing things. Little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your controller by creating a scope (as @apneadiving demonstrates), or by a method that encapsulates the query:

```
def self.amount_sum(user)
  where(:user_id => user).sum(:amount)
end
```

then in your controller:

```
@total_of_items = SomeModel.amount_sum(@user)
```

In this case I would use the method, because the scope is a little harder to read. Ryan Bates makes note of this in his [Railscast 215](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3):

> In the second named scope we’re using
>   a lambda. If you ever use one of these
>   in a named scope you might consider
>   using a class method instead
>   especially if you’re passing in a
>   large number of parameters or if the
>   content of the scope is complex. Ours
>   is fairly simple but we’ll turn it
>   into a class method anyway.

Your case is pretty simple, but I'd consider placing the logic inside a class method.

Comment: I prefer to use scopes, because they more clearly express the intent. So i would propose to use @apneadiving's answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is where `scopes` appear. In your model:

```
scope :sum_by_user, lambda {|user| where(:user_id => user).sum(:amount) }
```

Then in your controller:

```
@total_of_items = SomeModel.sum_by_user(@user)
```

You can even chain scopes which is really great.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html